# Debuging C++ exe from C# code

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I have a multithreaded C++ console application. I have written a C# program to use the execution file of my C++ code.

In order to run the C++ application via C#, I define a `Process` for the C++ application and use the below command to execute it:

```
_process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
```

After several hours of execution, CPU usage of the C++ program stays at 50% and the C++ program stops working! I do not know how should I understand what the problem is!

I tried attaching the C++ exe to C# program via `Debug -> Attach to Process` in visual studio 2014, but It does not show any useful information!

I have built C++ exe using release mode of visual studio and I also run C# code using release mode of visual studio.

Do you have any idea to debug this problem?

Comment: Build them both in Debug mode?

Comment: @nvoigt If I build them in Debug mode, It will take very long time to happen similar situation (maybe several days)! Since it is a multithreaded program and the problem probably related to multithreading, the similar situation might not happen in the debug mode!

Comment: Did you try? After all, debugging it tomorrow seems better than not debugging it today. Can you run (and debug) the C++ exe on it's own?

Comment: In a similar approach, what happens to the C++ application without the C# application opening the C++ output file?  For example, maybe one computer has both applications running, but the C# version is purposely not opening any file handles to the C++ output file.  In a separate test, another computer has only the C++ application running.  I would review how the C++ threads are opening and closing the output file.

Comment: @nvoigt You're right, but since it is time consuming, I want to use it as a last resort and I prefer to find a faster way to debug. Because my final application is using `C#` code, I want to debug it and I want to make sure that my final program does not have any bug.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD In such situation that you describe, program will stop running and the cpu usage of the program will stay at a constant value?

Comment: @Smn Sounds like the C++ exe has to be reviewed, looking closely at how and what conditions a thread starts, does the work, and correctly stops (goes to sleep, gracefully exits, terminates, etc.).  This looks like a reader / writer model.  If the C++ is managed .Net, then maybe the ReaderWriterLock class is available within the C++ exe.  Regardless, if the problem has not been resolved, then consult reference material on the reader / writer multi-threaded algorithm.  Two writer and/or reader-writer threads could be causing deadlock as they "wait" on each other to finish.

Comment: If you get no valueable information with "Attach to Process", check if "native code" is enabled there. If only "managed" is active, the debugger will not step into native (C++) code.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be viewed as much an answer, but as a good reference article to troubleshoot using the Windows API function OutputDebugString().  There is an excellent article by Mark Nelson on the Dr. Dobb's site, posted March 11, 2014: [Blundering into the One Definition Rule](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/blundering-into-the-one-definition-rule/240166489).

Within it are excellent details on how to take advantage of using the Microsoft [DebugView utlity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), in conjunction with the posted solution of a single header file when troubleshooting anything.  It is highly likely the short class definition on page two of the article is necessary to isolate where in the C++ exe the problem is.  Please review the article to fully understand the single line scoping and forced OutputDebugString() function call.  Using this helper class should reduce the time isolating where the 50% usage stalls and the C++ threads appear to deadlock.